# Converting character vectors to a factor with levels

Tags: r

One of the questions in my data frame asks people why they use a service. They ticked the reasons that apply and I've loaded the data into R. It's read the series of answers each person gave as a character string. I'd like to convert them into a factor with levels. The variable is called "Why_use_EPNET" and the levels I'm looking for in my factor would be "Discussing topics of interest", "Resource gathering", "Watching others discuss topics of interest" etc.

```
Why_use_EPNET
"Discussing topics of interest, Watching others discuss topics of interest"
"Discussing topics of interest, Resource gathering"
"Resource gathering"
"Resource gathering"
"Watching others discuss topics of interest"
```

R is currently reading each participants answer as a character vector. Ideally I'd like to convert the variable into a factor with different levels so R would recognise it as something like:

```
Why_use_EPNET
1,3
1,2
2
2
3
```

If that isn't possible I'll break the individual reasons up into a binary choice for each participant and then analyse:

```
Use_EPNET_for_Resource_gathering
Yes
Yes
Yes
No

Use_EPNET_for_Watching_others_discuss
No
Yes
No
Yes
```

Any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: as.numeric(as.factor)
?

Comment: We were wondering wether your data really is ordinal, or merely categorical. So far I've taken your question at face value and turned the character strings to ordinal values. This means they have a clear ordering, like good < better < best, unlike categorical values like red/green/blue, which don't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your current data structure looks something like this

```
k <- c(
  "Discussing topics of interest, Watching others discuss topics of interest",
  "Discussing topics of interest, Resource gathering",
  "Resource gathering",
  "Resource gathering",
  "Watching others discuss topics of interest")

Why_use_EPNET <- strsplit(k, ", *")
```

We can convert the answers to categorical with `factor()` and supplying a vector of levels.

```
lv <- c("Discussing topics of interest", 
        "Resource gathering",
        "Watching others discuss topics of interest")

Why_use_EPNET.o <- lapply(Why_use_EPNET, factor, levels=lv)
str(Why_use_EPNET.o)
# List of 5
#  $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "Discussing topics of interest",..: 1 3
#  $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "Discussing topics of interest",..: 1 2
#  $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "Discussing topics of interest",..: 2
#  $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "Discussing topics of interest",..: 2
#  $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "Discussing topics of interest",..: 3
```

You can then obtain the numeric values by using `as.numeric()`

```
lapply(Why_use_EPNET.o, as.numeric)
```

Comment: I don't think the use of `ordered` is appropriate here. There's no clear ordering of those factors and using `ordered` when it's not necessary can create problems latter. I'm wondering if you do understand that the order of values in the `levels` argument establishes the assignment to numeric values when using `factor`?. I can reverse my downvote if you edit you answer to use `factor`.

Comment: @42-: Neither do I, but the question is tagged [ordinal], so I figured I'd better.

Comment: Then you should attempt to clarify what was needed.

Comment: @42-: I'll keep the answer as is, pending comment from OP. If the measured response is a proxy for engagement or the like, ordering would make some sense. And I know how `factor()` works, thanksmuch.

Comment: You're absolutely right about it not being ordered (that's what you get when you write a comment in a hurry!). Sorry for the confusion everyone

Comment: @PsychBrief: Good to have that cleared up. I've changed my answer to categorical.

Comment: You are an absolute champion, you can have my first born child as a thank you. Much appreciated. Any ideas as to convert the resulting list into something more useful so I can plot it?